# server 2008 vpn

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, windows-server-2008-r2

I have enabled the vpn server on a server 2008 installation according to tutorials found on the internet, and after that, the server stopped receiving connections except VPN, or anything after somebody connected to the vpn server.

It has some more services (DNS, samba, http, etc) which were working perfectly until I installed and configured the vpn role, and they are working perfectly if i remove the vpn role. But if it is running, dns-http-etc are only available for users with an active vpn connection, on the server's internal (vpn) ip.

What should i modify, to enable them for any computer?

Comment: What exactly DID you do? "accordint to some tutorials" does not tell us waht crap tehy may have contained. Or what configurations of the firewall or the RRAS port filter, to make the setup "safer" which now blocky functionality for you.

Comment: I just completed the vpn setup wizard in the server manager. Before that everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

First place to look would be the firewall if it is enabled.

Make sure the right profile is active (usually Domain Profile), or disable it temporarily to test whether the services are accessible.